# How to Classify an Image in a Class and a Subclass?

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification

I am a beginner in Machine Learning and I have a situation where an Image needs to be classified into first a super class, then a subclass.
For Example,
I have a set of images of fruits, containing images of Mangoes, Banana, Peaches, Apples etc. Then each fruit can either be fresh or rotten. I have training set containing images of rotten and fresh fruits for each Fruit type.
So for a test image I need to classify which fruit it is (Mango, Banana, etc) and then whether it is fresh or rotten. 
I want to know how to approach this kind of problem

Answer (score 3):

### The simple solution

Have one classifier which can classify all the combinations:

- Fresh banana
- Rotten banana
- Fresh mango
- Rotten mango
- ...

### The good solution

Or have one network with multiple outputs. See the master Thesis of Marvin Teichmann for example. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07695

So one path of the network would be:

- Fresh vs Rotten

The other path of the network would be

- Banana vs Mango vs ...

The difference to the simple solution is that you can give a probability to the cases, e.g. for the ground truth "fresh banana" you might say 99% banana but only 42% fresh.

### The obvious solution

This one should not be done: have multiple classifiers

Comment: can you explain  why the obvious solution is bad?

Comment: The results are not so good because there are shared features for both tasks. If you give the network more labeled data it can generalize better. I think in Marvin Teichmann thesis you can read about that, IIRC

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to approach this kind of problem

Yes this is definately possible... (Probably Known as `Classification + Localization`)

Split the conv-nets into 2 parallel arch's at the very end , before We generally add a single-dense-layer after Feature Extraction, here you will have a split into two...(the image attached will make it clear)

- One to **detect** the Class i.e Which Fruit it is...
- Second to **classify** them as Rotten/Fresh

Have a look at this Image(From CS-231N Some credits apply)(in your case, replace Animals class and species with Fruits Class and State)(you don't need a bbox, so a modification to the arch will yield the results as desired provided that the **loss is calculated and used correctly** on both the ends of the network)

This Paper [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02913) probably address the same
[image]